# Qualcomm 2net hub SDK

Tags: android, ios, sdk, qualcomm

I really hope someone would have worked on this earlier.

We have purchased a qualcomm 2net hub device for a connected health project. 
https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/create-connected-experiences/wireless-health-2net

We need to integrate it with our application, for which we need access to their SDK. (Paid or free)

We are unable to find any link/reference/mention to the sdk on the qualcomm developer website.

All emails to Qualcomm support are never answered.

Did someone work on this before? Can someone please give me link to any reading material or such?

Really appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks much
Rgds

Comment: I am unable to add tags of "Qualcomm" and "2net" because of my score. Please consider these as tags. Thank you

Comment: Not sure about why I got a -1, at-least give me a reason so it will help me understand and not repeat that mistake in the future.. tx

Comment: What have your experiences been since you asked this question?

Comment: How did you solve this? If you are working with compliant BTLE health devices its not too hard to write your own app.